# How do I generate colour based on my JSON data in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I’m trying to figure out how I can generate color that will respond to my JSON data. So instead of typing something in like

```js
var applecolour, peachcolour, bananacolour;

function preload () { data =loadJSON (“fruits.json”); }

function setup () { createCanvas (200, 200); background (0); applecolour = color (20, 40, 40); peachcolour = color (20, 20, 20); bananacolour = color (30, 30, 30); }

function draw () { fill (applecolour); ellipse (20, 20, 40, 40); }
```

how would I go about writing it in a way where I don’t type in "fill (applecolour)" if I had about a 100 different fruits on my JSON list?

would it be something along the lines of this??? for (var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++)

Any help or recommendations would be great! if you could also point me to any references or examples other than the P5.JS library that would also be great!

Comment: you're on the right track with the for loop. The next steps are: 1. access the colour data for each fruit object within the array, 2. double check the JSON colour format and make sure it's compatible with what you can pass to `color()` and `fill()` (if not extract the useful data first). What does the fruit.json structure look like ? 

(e.g. if fruits[0].color is something like `[255,0,0]`, or `"#ff0000"` or [valid html colour name](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp):
`for(var i = 0 ; i < fruits.length; i++){ fill(fruits[i].color); circle(40 * i, 20, 30); }`

Comment: Showing a sample of fruits.json would make it easier to write an answer.